# How i can change page with "next" previous" buttons in the same node

Tags: views, 7, nodes, forms, webforms

i want create something like that 
:

[image]

and after clicking next page , the node doesn't change :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node from your screenshots is using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to create a multi-step form. The URL doesn't change because it's still the same node, the form's current step is just changing when you submit the form.

Without more information, I'm unsure if this is the same kind of functionality you're looking for, but when setting up a webform, I believe there is a "page break" component that you can add, which is what determines which components belong to which page. You could also use something like the [Webform Steps](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_steps) module to create a clickable progress bar for your form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [smart_paging](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_paging) module